# Python, Keras custom loss function based on prediction, which is not the input

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I'm trying to write a custom loss function in keras, which is based on multiple predictions of the model during training.
I have a previous list/dictionary like dict = {X1: [X2,X3,X4], X2:[X1, X6, X7]} etc.

Given input X1, I need predictions of X2,X3,X4 during training.

model.predict is not working, giving error
ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect thetensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 36)

```py
from keras.layers import * 
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K

input_tensor = Input(shape=(36,))
hidden       = Dense(100, activation='relu')(input_tensor)
out          = Dense(1, activation='linear')(hidden)

def custom_loss(input_tensor, dict):
    def inner(y_true, y_pred):
        X2 = dict[input_tensor][0]
        X3 = dict[input_tensor][1]
        X4 = dict[input_tensor][2]
        X2_pred = model.predict(X2)
        X3_pred = model.predict(X3)
        X4_pred = model.predict(X4)
        return K.mean(max(X2_pred, X3_pred, X4_pred)-y_true)

    return inner

custom_loss_final = custom_loss(input_tensor = input_tensor, dict = dict)

model        = Model(input_tensor, out)
model.compile(loss = custom_loss_final, optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x = Train_X, y = Train_y, batch_size= 100)
```

Edit based on **Anakin's** solution:
I tried your code, actually at np.append i needed to use axis = 0.

now I have:
INPUT_X.shape
 (100, 36)
INPUT_Y.shape
(100,3,36)

INPUT_X: I have 100 training-samples, each a 36 len array.
INPUT_Y: Those are the X2, X3, etc.

actually I don't even need Y_true in my code, cause I will use the model(X2) etc.

I passed them to model.fit as you suggested, inside the loss function i printed some type/shapes out:
 (input_tensor)
(?, 36)
 ("y_true")
(?, ?)
 (pred_y)
(?, 1)

I have no idea why y_true shape is (?,?) instead of (3,36). I can't put model(pred_y[:,0]), because I get:

ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'loss_56/dense_114_loss/model_57/dense_113/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?], [36,300].
 ##For clarity, 300 is the size of the hidden layer now.

Comment: I am not sure what you are exactly trying to do. Do you want to use the input tensor in your custom loss?

Comment: I wanted to use the input tensor to find X2,X3,X4, but as you suggested below It will be easier to pass directly with the Train_X, insted of looking for it inside.

Comment: Could you get the extra data as numpy arrays in your custom loss function similar to my `extra = data[:, 1:]`? You can just do `x2 = data[ :, 0, :]` , `x3 = data[:. 1, :]`. Verify check the slicing. Then maybe you need to reshape them to (100, 36). That's my intuition.

Comment: I suppose each of your X2, X3 etc have the shape `(None, 36)`

Comment: Not exactly, X2, X3 etc have the shape (36,).
(100,3,36) means 100 train sample, three X-es for each, each having 36 len.
I have problems with transforming the tensors int onto arrays (and I don't know why should I do it anyway, since i can model() a tensor.

The main problem is that it passes to the function with bad form ( ?,? shape, instead of ? 36)

Comment: If they are just a 1-dim array, you can just pass them in the custom loss wrapper, you don't have to pad them with your label.

Comment: No I can't do that, since I don't know what will be in the batch.
Or am I wrong?
But I really have no idea why padding with label is not working :(

Comment: I think it is possible to pass them as fixed sized arrays in custom loss wrapper so that they will retain the same shape and values across batches.

Comment: How will you filter for samples in the batch? Or you do that like a vocabulary?

Comment: (The X-es depend on the input, so can't have the same values across batches.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pad your label with extra data columns from input and write a custom loss. You can pass the extra prediction info w.r.t. your input as a numpy array like this

```
    def custom_loss(data, y_pred):

        y_true = data[:, 0]
        extra = data[:, 1:]
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1) + something with extra...


    def baseline_model():
        # create model
        i = Input(shape=(5,))
        x = Dense(5, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='linear')(i)
        o = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear')(x)
        model = Model(i, o)
        model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0005))
        return model


    model.fit(X, np.append(Y_true, extra, axis =1), batch_size = batch_size, epochs=90, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

The example is from a part of my code but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you! It will solve the dictionary problem as I will pass the inputs together with its pairs.
The other problem with the "how to predict" for those is the other problem. I tried meanwhile and maybe if instead of model.predict() I use model() will do the job. I will try it and write here.

Comment: I don't think using `model.predict()` inside a custom loss function is a particularly good idea. But I might be wrong. If you already know the other prediction values before the current training process, you can just pad them with your label as I showed. I don't know if you have some other constraints.

Comment: I think using `model` will do the job, make sure that X2, X3 etc are numpy arrays and not tensors

Comment: Could you get the extra data as numpy arrays in your custom loss function similar to my `extra = data[:, 1:]`? You can just do `x2 = data[ :, 0, :]` , `x3 = data[:. 1, :]`. Verify check the slicing. Then maybe you need to reshape them to (100, 36). That's my intuition.

Comment: Just an update, that your solution was indeed right, and I managed to hack in the X_... values by appending them into a one dimensional array, and feeding in the model.fit a 2 dimensional(rank/shape) array as you suggested.  

So: np.append(Y_true, extra, axis =1) must be 2 dimensional.  
First I tried as extra with more than 1 dimensions[each X into separate dimensions], but it didn't work.  
After that in the custom loss I managed to build them.    
x2 = data[ :, 0, :] is not working, since the dimension of y_true in the custom loss will be 2 dimensional whatever I do.  
Thank you!

Comment: For anyone struggling with the "No gradients" issue, make sure you are somehow using y_pred in your calculations involving x inputs. Otherwise, their gradients will not be captured by the GradientTape. Example: k.backend.cast(y_data[:, 1], tf.float32) + (y_pred[0] * 0)